# How to map root dictionaries using RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I've just started using RestKit. Given the JSON structure below, how do I configure an object mapping for `key 1` and `key 2`? I've successfully set up the object mapping for `key 3`.

```
{
  "key 1": "value",
  "key 2": "value",
  "key 3": [
    {
      "key": "value"
      "key": "value"
    },
    {
      "key": "value"
      "key": "value"
    }, 
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of RestKit are you using?

Comment: Whatever version the current master branch is. 0.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully use the RestKit object mapping without KVC you'll need to use two mappings - one inner mapping for the "key 3" and one outer mapping for "key 1" and "key 2".

You then define a relationship for the "key 3" key path. See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910709/relationships-not-connected-with-core-data-and-restkit) for details.